# unable to store a string as array variable in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to read a tab delimited file containing 4 columns and store each element of the column as an 1-dimensional array. Though the program prints the strings correctly as in the commented printf but it doesn't give me first_col[0] value and so on. My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main()
{
    FILE *int_file1;
    int BUF = 1024;

    char first_col[BUF],sec_col[BUF],third_col[BUF], fourth_col[BUF];

    int index=0,i=0;

    char *array1[BUF];

    int_file1=fopen("test.txt","r");

    if(int_file1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(!feof(int_file1))
        {
            fscanf(int_file1,"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t     [^\n]\n",first_col,sec_col,third_col,fourth_col);
//            printf("%s\n",first_col);
            strcpy(first_col,array1[index]);
            index++;
        }
     }

    fclose(int_file1);    

    for(i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",array1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The inputfile test.txt has the following elements:

34932 13854 13854 2012-01-07

### 172098 49418 53269 2012-01-07

### -

Please help!!

Comment: You might check whether fscanf returns 4; putting \n in fscanf is useless because blank characters in the format do match for 0,1,+ blanks in the file. If you want to check a \n, try %[\n] and count +1 for fscanf result.

Comment: Reverse your `strcpy` parameters; the first argument is the destination, not the source.

Comment: And note on top of everything else, [`while(!feof(int_file1))`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) is almost certainly *wrong*. You never check whether the invoke of `fscanf()` actually *worked*.

Comment: Reversing strcpy parameters didn't work. Still segmentation fault.

Comment: please suggest how to check or invoke fscanf

Comment: tried adding this snippet but could get only first value of first_col and then a segmentation fault [CODE]   while(fscanf(int_file1,"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\n]",first_col,sec_col,third_col,fourth_col) == 4)
  {
   printf("%s\t",first_col);
   strcpy(array1[index],first_col);
   index++;
  }
[\CODE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors:

1. In `strcpy(first_col,array1[index])`, you have swapped between the source string and the destination string. So you should change it to `strcpy(array1[index],first_col)`.
2. You have not initialized any of the entries in `array1`, so an expression such as `array1[index]` is essentially junk. Hence, before commencing `strcpy(array1[index],first_col)`:

   Set `array1[index] = malloc(strlen(first_col)+1);`

Oh, and don't forget to `free(array1[i])` after printing it...

Comment: Or `malloc(strlen(first_col) + 1)` rather, since this seems to be C and not C++. Otherwise, good advice.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It did work after doing the corrections. However, I am getting a new line character added to the second row variable of first_col. Please suggest how to get rid of this new line character??

Comment: Hey no problem man, then how about some credit up there? I don't know the structure of your input file, so I can't help you with it, but I'm guessing that you need to add `\n` somewhere after the second `%`...

Comment: No idea how to give credits in this forum.. Im very new to d forum sorry.. but yes my tons n tons of thanks!! I wanted to get rid of the \n not bring it.. But hope I can figure it out by little googling.. Thanks once again!!

Comment: Click on the V next to the answer :)